# PHP str_replace array to remove spaces and reaplce with - and / with - also issue

Tags: php

Im having an issue with my following snippet, its more or less working.... what i need to do is replace spaces with - and also want to replace / with - but its adding double for / as its applying for spaces either side of it and not sure how to resolve.

PHP

```
$optimise_product_name_pre = "Simplified PHP Invoice / Billing System";
$optimise_product_name = str_replace(array(" ","/"), array("-",""), $optimise_product_name_pre);
return $optimise_product_name;
```

OUTPUT:

> simplified-php-invoice--billing-system

EXPECTED:

> simplified-php-invoice-billing-system

Comment: Did you really want the resulting string to be all lower case?

Comment: Refer to this link. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp that will give you explanation on how str_replace works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes string replacement cannot be done accurately using one `str_replace()` so all you have to do is split the process into 2 seperate `str_replace()` calls

```
$optimise_product_name_pre = "Simplified PHP Invoice / Billing System";

$optimise_product_name = str_replace(" / ", "-", $optimise_product_name_pre);
$optimise_product_name = str_replace(" ", "-", $optimise_product_name);

echo $optimise_product_name;
```

Result

```
Simplified-PHP-Invoice-Billing-System
```

If you really wanted the resulting string to be all lower case then add a strtolower() like this

```
$optimise_product_name_pre = "Simplified PHP Invoice / Billing System";

$optimise_product_name = str_replace(" / ", "-", $optimise_product_name_pre);
$optimise_product_name = str_replace(" ", "-", $optimise_product_name);

echo strtolower($optimise_product_name);
```

Result

```
simplified-php-invoice-billing-system
```

> Of course replace my `echo` with the `return` you were using if this is indeed in a function.

On closer examination this also works

```
$optimise_product_name_pre = "Simplified PHP Invoice / Billing System";
$optimise_product_name = str_replace(array(" /"," "), array("","-"), $optimise_product_name_pre);

echo strtolower($optimise_product_name);
```